# Не понимаю как решить проблему

Tags: python

2 день изучаю python, не получается вывести функцию. Ошибка объект не вызывается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь добавлять код в виде текста, а не в виде картинки. Так его легче читать, можно копировать и по нему можно проводить поиск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пожалуйста прилагайте код текстом а не картинкой**

Проблема в отступах. У вас `return ob` находится внутри самой функции `ob` поэтому опустите её ниже в функцию `dec`

```
def dec(fam):
    def ob():
        ...
        return ob
```

Надо заменить на

```
def dec(fam):
    def ob():
        ...
    return ob
```

Comment: Спасибо большое